# How can I use the extern class?

Tags: c++, class, extern

I try to use `extern class SLL;` in Main.cpp

and I define class name of SLL in user.cpp like below.

```
class SLL {
public:
    Node *headLink; 

    SLL() {
        headLink = NULL; 
    }
    void createFirst(int data) {
        Node *tmp = headLink; 
        tmp->data = data; 
        tmp->nextNode = headLink; 

        tmp = headLink; 
        ListSize++; 
    }
    const int getListSize() {
        return ListSize; 
    }

    void deleteList(int idx) {
        Node *tmp = headLink; 
        Node *swapNode; 
        Node *deleteNode; 

        for (int i = 0; i < idx - 1; i++) {
            tmp = tmp->nextNode; 
        }
        deleteNode = tmp->nextNode; 
        swapNode = deleteNode->nextNode;

        tmp->nextNode = swapNode; 

        free(deleteNode); 
    }
private:
    int ListSize = 0; 
};
```

But it is Error "SLL is incomplete format"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the EXACT error message, copy/pasted from your compiler's output? Which line of code EXACTLY is it complaining about? And BTW, your implementations of `createFirst()` and `deleteList()` are wrong.

Comment: Did you have any `user.hpp` file where class `SLL` is declared? You need to include it in `Main.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Classes cannot be `extern`. You shoud define the SLL class in user.hpp and `#include "user.hpp"` from main.cpp.